# Data update when navigating to a screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a question about React-Navigation.

I have two screens being: ScreenA and ScreenB.

Inside ScreenA I have data obtained from the database.

TelaB adds data to this same database.

After ScreenB adds data to the database, it navigates back to ScreenA but the data is not updated. I would like to update the data only when this browsing occurs to avoid unnecessary requests.

Is it possible to invoke a method like forceupdate from ScreenA when ScreenB navigates to Screen A? When screenA is first mounted, data is obtained within the componentDidMount method. If there is a way of "reassembling" every time I navigate to ScreenA, that would resolve too.

Screens are in a DrawerNavigation

Sorry for any mistake, I'm using a translator.

Comment: I think the solution in your case is ScreenA load data from store when you update data in ScreenB just after data successfully updated in database refresh the data in the store and it will be updated in ScreenA ( use redux for this case )

Comment: I am a beginner using redux, would I always have to keep a copy of the data inside the store? I could perform an update every cycle within render () but would make many requests to the server with the database

Comment: no need to update in render just update after successfully adding data to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you could do would be to use `redux` and having your most used data that you need for multiple screens in one spot.

You can read about it at redux's official site : https://redux.js.org/

The other solution if you just need to communicate between these two screen can be done by using `react-navigation`.

`react-navigation` offers a HOC named `withNavigationFocus`. Adding the HOC to your screenA component you can check if it's passing from a blurred state to a focused one

For example:

```
import {withNavigationFocus} from react-navigation;

...

...

...

componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    if( prevProps.isFocused !== this.props.isFocused && this.props.isFocused === true){
        //Update your data in screenA triggering a setState()
    }

}

...

...

...

export default withNavigationFocus(ScreenA);
```